# In the java visualizer, why do String items of an array have a pointer to them, whereas variable assignments to them don't?

Tags: arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to understand why the java visualizer draws pointers to array items assigned to Strings, but doesn't draw pointers from variables to a String when they were assigned to one. Here is:
[array with pointers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ns9S.png),
[variable without pointers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/redMe.png)
does such a dichotomy between assigning things to Strings in the java visualizer have any implications for our programs? I am wondering if Strings are still immutable even in this pointer situation. Conceptually, is anything different happening in the way passing by is occurring between these diagrams?

I have tried seeing if this is consistent behaviour in the context of arrays, and that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are Java objects that are kept in memory and can be accessed using pointers.

A reference to the array's memory location is saved in the variable when an array is assigned to it.

As a result, pointers to each individual array item, which are actually objects in memory, are displayed when the array is displayed by the Java visualizer.

When a String is assigned to a variable, a new object in memory is created, and the variable stores a reference to this new object.

Because Strings are immutable, the contents of the object cannot be changed once it is created. The Java visualizer does not display a pointer to the original String object when it displays the variable because it already points to it.

The way in which the Java visualizer shows arrays and Strings differently shouldn't have any implications for how your program works. Whether pointers are displayed or not, the strings remain immutable.

String is an immutable object that is saved in memory as a new object and accessed by reference, an array is an object that is stored in memory and accessed by reference.